# Issues of gcc optimization with rdtsc

Tags: c, optimization, gcc

I am using rdtsc and cpuid instructions (using volatile inline assembly instructions) to measure the CPU cycles of a program. The rdtsc instruction gives realistic results for my programs on Linux (with speed optimization -o2 -fomit-frame-pointer) and Windows (using speed optimization options C compiler for MS Visual Studio 2008 (I think its VC 9.0)).

Recently, I implemented a new program, which uses a lot of table-lookups and stuff like this. However, the rdtsc measurements of this program with gcc optimization on Linux always results in wrong measurements (very small number of CPU cycles) than I expect. The rdtsc measurements of the same program while running on Windows (compiled with optimizations and compiler I mentioned above) are realistic and agree to out expectations.

My question is there any way gcc optimization move the volatile assembly instructions some where to produce the above mentioned behaviour?

My code for the timers is given below:

```
#define TIMER_VARS                                                 \
  uint32 start_lo, start_hi;                                       \
  uint32 ticks_lo, ticks_hi

#define TIMER_START()                                              \
  __asm__ __volatile__                                             \
     ("rdtsc"                                                      \
     : "=a" (start_lo), "=d" (start_hi) /* a = eax, d = edx*/      \
     : /* no input parameters*/                                    \
     : "%ebx", "%ecx", "memory")

#define TIMER_STOP()                                               \
  __asm__ __volatile__                                             \
     ("rdtsc"                                                      \
     "\n        subl %2, %%eax"                                    \
     "\n        sbbl %3, %%edx"                                    \
     : "=&a" (ticks_lo), "=&d" (ticks_hi)                          \
     : "g" (start_lo), "g" (start_hi)                              \
     : "%ebx", "%ecx", "memory")
```

I would be very thankful if some body could suggest some ideas on this.

thanks,

Comment: There are differences in behaviour between single core and multi core machines (multicore machines sometimes sync the clocks), also a tdtsc sometimes will drop the caches or the TLB , there are differences between Intel and AMD, and there are differences between chip dye versions. Also: rdtsc is (can be) a restricted instruction which might even be handled by a trap. (I guess a VM will do something like that) I think the compiler has little or no influence. Check the compilers assembly output for that .

Comment: I am facing this issue on machines with Intel single-core processors.

Comment: I just added the code for my timers. May be this could give some further clue.

Comment: When running in performance mode, have you ensured to set your testing app with single thread, affinity to one core and the CPU clock speed forced to MAX (i.e. no auto frequency tuning)?

Comment: You don't need `%ebx` and `%ecx` clobbers.  Are those left-over from using `cpuid` to serialize?  You can use `lfence` instead.  Anyway, see [Get CPU cycle count?](//stackoverflow.com/a/51907627); you could just use the `__rdtsc()` intrinsic.

Answer (score 3):

In order to prevent an inline `rdtsc` function from being moved across any loads/stores/other operations, you should both write the asm as `__asm__ __volatile__` and include `"memory"` in the clobber list. Without doing the latter, GCC is prevented from removing the asm or moving it across any instructions that could need the results (or change the inputs) of the asm, but it could still move it with respect to unrelated operations. The `"memory"` clobber means that GCC cannot make any assumptions about memory contents (any variable whose address has been potentially leaked) remaining the same across the asm, and thus it becomes much more difficult to move it. However, GCC may *still* be able to move the asm across instructions that only modify local variables whose address was never taken (since they are not `"memory"`).

Oh, and as wildplasser said in a comment, **check the asm output** before you waste a lot of time on this.

Comment: I had not thought of the explicit barrier. Also note that because of the instruction barrier, the CPU will have to drain the pipelines, leading to performance loss. It is a Heisenticker ...

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much impossible to avoid.

Comment: Yes, the in-line assembly instructions are written in `__asm__ __volatile__`. As per your suggestions, I added the `"memory"` to the clobber list but it also did not help.

Comment: I just added the code for my timers. May be this could give some further clue.

Comment: @R.. Please can you confirm whether my understanding of your answer is correct? Are you saying that without `"memory"`, the `__volatile__` prevents GCC optimising the asm out, but it still may be reordered (wrt unrelated instructions)? The `"memory"` prevents the asm from being reordered. Is that correct?

Comment: The `"memory"` prevents it from being reordered with respect to operations that read or write "memory" (any object whose address might be visible), but as far as I know there's no way to "absolutely" prevent reordering.

Comment: @R.. Also, please could you elaborate on `GCC may still be able to move the asm across instructions that only modify local variables whose address was never taken`. Does that mean something like `int j=1;`? We never explicitly refer to its address?

Comment: For example (assuming `rdtsc` is a `static inline` function using the asm) `int f(int a) { unsigned t = rdtsc(); a*=a; return rdtsc()-t+a; }` there is no ordering between the `a*=a` operation and the two `rdtsc`'s. There's no *intentional* reordering, but the possibility of reordering is just a consequence of the way code generation works when there's no cross dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is(was) correct, but the code I once used was:

```
#define rdtscll(val) \
      __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc" : "=A" (val))

typedef unsigned unsigned long long Ull;

static inline Ull myget_cycles (void)
{
Ull ret;

rdtscll(ret);
return ret; 
}
```

I remember it was "slower" on Intel than on AMD. YMMV.

Comment: It is important to note that your solution was not measuring correctly as emitting rdtsc alone will not prevent the CPU from reordering it while execution. Either use lfence or cpuid instruction before rdtsc or use rdtscp on newer CPUs. Check wikipedia it describes it correctly.

Comment: @tothphu: you are completely correct. cpuid is needed if reordering is to be feared. If reordering is not a problem (eg because of an intervening function call), the cpuid could be omitted.)

Comment: `"=A"` will miscompile in 64-bit code.  You'll only get the low half of the 64-bit timestamp.  (That's fine if you're subtracting two timestamps and the interval is small enough, like about a second for a 4.3GHz CPU.)  See [Get CPU cycle count?](//stackoverflow.com/a/51907627) for correct code.